# Predicate into clause form

Tags: predicate-logic

How would one convert this into clause form?

(1) ∀x[Dog(x) ⇒ Animal(x)]

Some hits, or literally anything is appreciated..!

Thanks in regards,
O. Dripp

Comment: For every creature on Earth, if it is a (kind) of dog; so it  (certaily) is an animal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Resolution in first order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#Informal_explanation) :

> To recast the reasoning using the resolution technique, first the [clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)) must be converted to [conjunctive normal form (CNF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form). In this form, all quantification becomes implicit: universal quantifiers on variables ($x, y, \ldots$) are simply omitted as understood, while existentially-quantified variables are replaced by [Skolem functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form).

Thus, $\forall x \ (Px \to Qx)$ will be converted into :

> $\lnot Px \lor Qx$.

---

Assuming that we have to use *Resolution* with :

> (1) $∀x[Dog(x) \to Animal(x)]$, (2) $∀y[Animal(y) \to Die(y)]$ and (3) $Dog(Fido)$

we have to convert them into :

> $\lnot Dog(x) \lor Animal(x)$
>
> $\lnot Animal(y) \lor Die(y)$
>
> $Dog(Fido)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let's say my question is like this:

Comment: (1) ∀x[Dog(x) ⇒ Animal(x)] 
(2) ∀y[Animal(y) ⇒ Die(y)] 
(3) Dog(fido)

Comment: and I have to convert it into clause form?